# Jquery chosen plug-ins background image can't be seen with firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-chosen

Normally chosen plug-in is working without any problem with most of the browsers even old ie versions.

But today i noticed the last firefox version has got a problem with plug-in.

The image of dropdown menu disappeared:

[image]

same problem can be seen from the official site

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: You should add an issue on Github at [https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dude the plugin is showing the image of dropdown menu on my pc on all browsers latest version incl firefox chrome ie.